# jasmine-maven-plugin and jasmine.log

Tags: jasmine

I can't find a way to see the results of calling jasmine.log when running specs with the jasmine-maven-plugin. Has anyone else succeeded at this? Here's an example spec:

```
describe("foo", function() {
it("bloop", function() {
jasmine.log("bloop");
});
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem that Jasmine-Maven plugin took into account that Jasmine had a .log

See the following GitHub Issue Entry => https://github.com/searls/jasmine-maven-plugin/issues/45

EDIT: lol, I just saw that it was you who posted that issue on Github so I am pretty sure you know about it :) Will be useful for anyone else finding this though